# Differences in for-loops. Swift v.s. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, for-loop

In this loop we have the potential to reduce the number of items in the loop while processing it. This code works fine in Obj-C, but the Swift loops don't get the message that an item has been removed and end up overflowing the array.

In Objective-C, we had:

```
            for(int i = 4; i < staticBlocks.count; i++)
            {
                PlayerSprite* spr = [staticBlocks objectAtIndex:i];
                [spr setPosition:CGPointMake(spr.position.x, spr.position.y-1)];

                if(spr.position.y < -1000)
                {
                    [staticBlocks removeObject:spr];
                    [spr removeFromParent];
                }

                if(spr.blockTypeIndex == Block_Type_Power_Up)
                {
                    [spr update];
                }
            }
```

In Swift I know of these options:

```
               //for i in 4.stride(to: staticBlocks.count, by: 1){ //crashes
               //for i in 4..<staticBlocks.count{  //crashes

               for var i = 4; i < staticBlocks.count; i += 1 { //works, but is deprecated

                    let spr = staticBlocks.objectAtIndex(i) as! PlayerSprite
                    spr.position = CGPointMake(spr.position.x, spr.position.y-1)

                    if(spr.position.y < -1000)
                    {
                        staticBlocks.removeObject(spr)
                        spr.removeFromParent()
                        //break
                    }

                    if(spr.blockTypeIndex == k.BlockType.PowerUp)
                    {
                        spr.update()
                    }
                }
```

In this specific case, it really isn't a problem for me to use a break statement (which is currently commented out) to kill the loop and prevent the crash, but it doesn't seem like the proper fix. I assume there will come a time when I need to know how do do this correctly. Is there a non deprecated way to do a for loop, one which processes the count each pass?

A related, unanswered question.
[Is the for loop condition evalutaed each loop in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235595/is-the-for-loop-condition-evalutaed-each-loop-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Swift you cannot remove items from an array while you are iterating over it.

From this question [Removing from array during enumeration in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323848/removing-from-array-during-enumeration-in-swift)
you can see that you should be using the `filter` function instead of using a for loop.

For example, don't do this:

```
for (index, aString: String) in enumerate(array) {
    //Some of the strings...
    array.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Do something like this:

```
var theStrings = ["foo", "bar", "zxy"]

// Filter only strings that begins with "b"
theStrings = theStrings.filter { $0.hasPrefix("b") }
```

(Code example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324072/3830876))

Additionally, it should be noted that filter won't update the array, it will return a new one. You can set your array to be equal to that array afterwards.

An additional way to solve the issue, from the same question is to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33116370/3830876):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (i,num) in a.enumerate().reverse() {
    a.removeAtIndex(i)
}
print(a)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to use filter in my specific situation. I have not used it before, perhaps it can do what I want but I don't really understand.
What I did realize is that the answer directly above the one you linked works for my situation.

Comment: I edited my answer to include that part of the code too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to link to a specific answer, but this code did what I needed. Marking as duplicate now.

[Removing from array during enumeration in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323848/removing-from-array-during-enumeration-in-swift)

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (i,num) in a.enumerate().reverse() {
    a.removeAtIndex(i)
}
```